# git clone get an empty directory except .git

Tags: android, git

When I do try to get android kernel source

> git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/exynos.git

I end up getting an empty directory except .git.

And I am on 'master' branch.

How can I get the source code?

I think the repository has code, since I receive 560 MB of data

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/exynos.git
Cloning into 'exynos'...
remote: Sending approximately 540.86 MiB ...
remote: Counting objects: 43365, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (1475/1475)
remote: Getting sizes: 100% (425/425)
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7574351/7574351)
remote: Total 2478827 (delta 2063341), reused 2478452 (delta 2063298)
Receiving objects: 100% (2478827/2478827), 540.64 MiB | 199 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2063553/2063553), done.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `master` branch is empty. Try:

```
git checkout android-exynos-3.4
```

or

```
git checkout android-exynos-manta-3.4-kitkat-mr1
```

View all branches via

```
git branch -a
```